# Каким образом React подключается при build в create-react-app

Tags: reactjs

Я могу добавить React посредством вставки тега script:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
```

А потом использовать React и ReactDOM:

```
const e = React.createElement;
```

При публикации сайта на продакшен мне нужно будет указать другие ссылки в атрибуте src в теге script.
При построении проекта через Create React App происходит минификация, сжатие, преобразование jsx в js и так далее. Однако после построения в папке build в index.html, я не замечаю тегов script с атрибутами, указывающими на импорт React и ReactDOM.
**Вопрос:**
Каким образом при построении приложения через Create React App происходит импорт React, ReactDOM и сопутствующих им модулей?
P.S. Построение приложения необязательно должен выполнять Create React App, это может делать индивидуально настроенный webpack и Babel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При построении приложения с помощью webpack импорт React, ReactDOM и сопутствующих им модулей происходит там, где Вы их импортируете в своём коде на Javascript. Получившийся файл, например, bundle.js со всеми зависимостями внутри него подключается в теге script файла index.html. Таким образом, отдельно эти библиотеки подключать в файле index.html не нужно.